# How to re-start counting from a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a table with the following three columns:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3
1      A       Cat
2      B       Dog
3      C       Lion
4      M       Deer
5      X       Cow
6      P       Orange
```

Now in another cell, I want to copy values from col3 if my lookup value matches to col1 value. Suppose my lookup value is 1 then Cat should be copied followed by all other values in consecutive columns.

```
If Lookup Value -> 1, then the output should be

grp1    grp2    grp3
Cat     Dog     Lion
Deer    Cow     Orange

If lookup value -> 3, then the output should be

grp1    grp2    grp3
Lion    Deer    Cow
Orange  Cat     Dog
```

So it's a kind of circular copying from the original table.

I tried using vlookup formula

```
vlookup(lookup_val,$Col1_Row1$Col3_Row6,3,FALSE)
```

and copied it to all the output cells by adding:

```
Col_number + Row_number - 1
```

to the LookUp value, so the output cells have the formula:

```
grp1   vlookup(lookup_val,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)    vlookup(lookup_val+3,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)
grp2   vlookup(lookup_val+1,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)    vlookup(lookup_val+4,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)
grp3   vlookup(lookup_val+2,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)    vlookup(lookup_val+5,$C1_R1$C3_R6,3,FALSE)
```

But this doesn't work as once you have lookup value greater than 1 the formula gets an error due to lookup value in subsequent cells adding upto more than 6.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Did you think to place a condition `=IF...` to avoid it?

Comment: Please pick your app, it's either Excel or Google Sheets. While the two share some similarities they are in a lot of ways different.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego How will use of =IF help because it will check the error but will not copy the values as I want if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: @JvdV Changed to google sheets.

Comment: In your case, the solution will be easy with VBA, but as you are looking for direct formula, in the scenario where your index is out of your range you will need another formula (`IF` will be required) or just loop the data.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can use a combination of MOD and VLOOKUP:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(mod(row(A1:C2)*3+column(A1:C2)+D2-5,6)+1,A2:C7,3,false))
```

[image]

It's fairly easy to generalise it for different-sized ranges.